# CreateDelegate using one general method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to create various type of delegates with just one general method like this.

```
public static object Boo(params object[] args) {
    return null;
}
```

```
MethodInfo boo = /* MethodInfo of Boo */

// Boo's arg.Length should be `0`
Action action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), null, boo);

Func<int> action2 = (Func<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>), null, boo);
Func<string, string> action3 = (Func<string, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, string>), null, boo);
```

So, If you invoke `action3` just like this

```
var ret = action3.Invoke("booo");
```

Boo's `args.Length` should be 1 and `ret` is `null`.

Is it possible in C#?

- No `dynamic`, `generic` or `linq.exprssion` sry.

### Update

This one should be done with `Reflection`. Above 3 delegates are just example. The type of delegates will be decied in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first define a delegate for your general method:

```
public delegate object BooDelegate(params object[] args);
```

You can use extension methods in the following manner:

```
public static class DelegatesProviderExtensions
{
    public static Func<int> GetFuncOfInt(this BooDelegate booDelegate) => () => (int) booDelegate();

    public static Action GetAction(this BooDelegate booDelegate) => () => booDelegate();

    public static Func<string, string> GetFuncOfStringString(this BooDelegate booDelegate) =>
        s => booDelegate(s) as string;
}
```

And test:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BooDelegate boo1 = objects => 1;
    BooDelegate boo2 = objects =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Boo!");
        return null;
    };
    BooDelegate boo3 = objects => $"{objects[0]} World";

    Console.WriteLine(boo1.GetFuncOfInt()());
    boo2.GetAction()();
    Console.WriteLine(boo3.GetFuncOfStringString()("Hello"));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can make your extension methods more complete and validate errors, and give feedback, etc, etc

Comment: Brilliant! :-) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Can you just do:

```
Action action = () => Boo();
Func<int> action2 = () => (int)Boo();
Func<string, string> action3 = x => (string)Boo(x);
```

If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Finally done with this way
https://github.com/pjc0247/SlowSharp/blob/master/Slowsharp/Runner/Runner.Lambda.cs

I think it can't be shorten without Linq.Expression.